# How to initialize the SteamAPI in Unreal Engine C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5, steamworks-api

I'm trying to initialize the SteamAPI in the Init function on my custom game instance class.

Here's the code I've used.

```
void UCPP_GameInstance_Base::Init()
{
    Super::Init();

    SteamAPI_RestartAppIfNecessary(MyAppID);

    if (SteamAPI_Init())
    {
        SteamUtils()->SetGameLauncherMode(true);
    }
}
```

Since putting this in I'm getting a crash when pressing play on my game every time without fail. I'm getting the following error message back;

> KERNELBASE UnrealEditor_MyGame!__delayLoadHelper2()
> [D:\a_work\1\s\src\vctools\delayimp\delayhlp.cpp:375]
> UnrealEditor_MyGame!_tailMerge_steam_api64_dll()
> UnrealEditor_Engine UnrealEditor_UnrealEd UnrealEditor_UnrealEd
> UnrealEditor_UnrealEd UnrealEditor_UnrealEd UnrealEditor_UnrealEd
> UnrealEditor_UnrealEd UnrealEditor_UnrealEd UnrealEditor_UnrealEd
> UnrealEditor UnrealEditor UnrealEditor UnrealEditor UnrealEditor
> UnrealEditor kernel32 ntdll

The crash is specifically being caused by the if (SteamAPI_Init()) line of code. The code compiles correctly and I seem to have access to all the SteamAPI functions, so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks

Comment: Do you have the steam dlls and steamid file in the same directory as the executable?

Comment: I've got the dll here in my packaged builds;

"...\Engine\Binaries\ThirdParty\Steamworks\Steamv153\Win64\steam_api64.dll"

Should I be manually placing it in the exe directory or is there something I need to do to get it there? With the steamid file, I was under the impression this was generated upon starting the game and deleted upon exiting, should I be manually creating this? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if the steam client is running while you're testing?

Comment: I haven't checked specifically, but I still get the same crash even when running a build directly through Steam

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has this issue in the future, I think I've worked out the cause.

I was trying to use the Steam SDK v1.58a as this was the latest version. However, I'm on UE5.1, which should be using SDK v1.53a I think.

Since swapping out the SDK version in my project, this specific error has gone away.